# How to Integrate Swift CocoaPods with a bridging header file

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, bridging-header

I've recently started doing iOS and I'm attempting to integrate the Vitamio Objective-C library with my Swift Project.  I use CocoaPods to import various swift libraries.  Vitamio is integrated with a bridging-header file.

Bridging-Header File

```
#ifndef inclub_Bridging_Header_h
#define inclub_Bridging_Header_h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "VDefines.h"
#import "VPlayerManageDef.h"
#import "VMediaPlayer.h"
#import "VMediaPlayerDelegate.h"
#import "VMediaExtracterDef.h"
#import "VMediaExtracter.h"

#endif /* inclub_Bridging_Header_h */
```

PodFile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'inclub' do
    pod "Player", "~> 0.2.0"
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 3.0'
    pod 'ObjectMapper', '~> 2.2'
    pod 'UIImageViewAlignedSwift'
    post_install do |installer|
        installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Sample Swift File

```
import Alamofire
import Foundation

class BackEnd {
    typealias JsonResponseHandler = (_ response: DataResponse<String>) -> Void
    typealias ErrorHandler = (_ error: Error) -> Void

    let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
    var dataTask: URLSessionDataTask?


    static func tabletLogIn(user: String, password: String, responseHandler: @escaping JsonResponseHandler,  errorHandler: @escaping ErrorHandler) {
        let url = UrlFactory.getLogInUrl(user: user, pass: password)
        print("Calling URL: " + url);

        makeRequest(urlString: url, method: .post, responseHandler: responseHandler, errorHandler: errorHandler)
    }

    static func getAdOrderInfo(orderId: String, responseHandler: @escaping JsonResponseHandler,  errorHandler: @escaping ErrorHandler) {
        let url = UrlFactory.getAdOrderInfoUrl(orderId: orderId)
        print("Calling URL: " + url);

        makeRequest(urlString: url, method: .post, responseHandler: responseHandler, errorHandler: errorHandler)
    }

    static func getDetailedMusicChannels(responseHandler: @escaping JsonResponseHandler,  errorHandler: @escaping ErrorHandler) {
        let url = UrlFactory.getMusicChannelUrl()
        print("Calling URL: " + url);

        makeRequest(urlString: url, method: .post, responseHandler: responseHandler, errorHandler: errorHandler)
    }

    static func getTvChannels(responseHandler: @escaping JsonResponseHandler,  errorHandler: @escaping ErrorHandler) {
        let url = UrlFactory.getTvChannelUrl()
        print("Calling URL: " + url);

        makeRequest(urlString: url, method: .post, responseHandler: responseHandler, errorHandler: errorHandler)
    }

    static func makeRequest(urlString: String, method: HTTPMethod, responseHandler: @escaping JsonResponseHandler, errorHandler: @escaping ErrorHandler) {
        Alamofire.request(urlString, method: method).validate().responseString {response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                responseHandler(response)
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                errorHandler(error)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example file the Alamofire import works but the first error message displayed in no class for type DataResponse.

Whenever, I add the Bridging Header File to project -> target -> Objective-C Briding Header the Vitamio library compiles; however, none of the classes added by my CocoaPods work.

If I remove the bridging header file the CocoaPods work but Vitamio does not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a Pod repository for `Vitamio`? I'm not sure what you are trying to do with `Podfile`.

Comment: There is not a Pod repo for Vitamio

Answer (score 3):

When you use "use_frameworks!" in the Podfile as you are, you don't need to import anything in the bridging header. Cocoapods is making frameworks for each of those pods for you, so you can just import them as if they were common frameworks directly on your swift file:

```
import Vitamio
```

The name might be different, as I don't know this particular library.

Edit: seems I misunderstood the problem a bit, waiting on more info.

Comment: Yeah.  I read something to this effect, but don't quite understand it.  Vitamio does not have a Podfile to import hence why it is still being done in the briding header file.

Comment: @AdamW can you post a sample swift file where pods stop working?

Comment: Added the sample file

Comment: @AdamW what's the problem you're getting there? Alamofire won't import?

Comment: The import works fine.  But it does not recognize the class DataResponse

Comment: Can you try being more specific and using Alamofire.DataResponse instead of just DataResponse? Maybe it's conflicting with something in your new library, which is imported on every file because of the bridging header. Can you paste the exact error you get?

Comment: So after adding Alamofire to the beginning it is showing the message:  No type named 'DataResponse' in module 'Alamofire'

Comment: This holds true to every class that is imported i.e. No type named Mappable in module ObjectMapper

Comment: From the reading I've been doing, it must have something to do with how the header files are inserted and Cocoa Pods overwriting them.  I'm thinking about trying out Carthage instead.

Comment: Not sure if the question is answered here.

Comment: The answer for "How to Integrate Swift CocoaPods with a bridging header file" if you're using "use_frameworks!" (gathered from his initial post) is "You don't need a bridging header". The problems he's having are intrinsic to the crappy library he's using :P